# Python error "not well-formed (invalid token)"

Tags: python, xml

I have some software that outputs an XML file that I am trying to read with python, so I can get the results and add them into my database.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
with open('E:/uk_bets_history.xml', 'r') as xml_file:
    xml_tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
```

I am getting the error `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1` but I am unsure why it is not formatted correctly.

I am not in control of how the file is created as this is done by some other software I own.

The example xml is here: http://jarrattperkins.com/uk_bets_history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File you've provided as example use [UTF-8 with BOM](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) encoding, so you need to use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) with `encoding` argument:

```
open("FILE_PATH", encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: Idk why, but this is the most helpful answer I found. A lot of other answers to almost the same question does not work. But it helps to read utf-16 in Python 3.9.

`with open(file=file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as xml_txt:
                root = ET.fromstring((xml_txt.read().encode('utf-8')), ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file=file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as xml_txt:                 
  root = ET.fromstring((xml_txt.read().encode('utf-8')), ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
```

This works for me. Thanks Jules_96

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).